# iOS release memory management

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management

I had a question, regarding iOS memory management. Does iOS release memory instantly after calling release message with initial retain counter equal to 1?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, yes. Release decrements the retain counter, and if it becomes 0, 'dealloc' is called and it is freed immediately. However, you shouldn't rely on the value of  the retain counter, as it doesn't give any useful information. Follow the paradigms or use ARC.

Comment: `retainCount` never becomes zero, the object is dealloc'ed when `retainCount` would become zero.